# How to escape duplicated value in Jquery each loop?

Tags: jquery

I want to removed all duplicated value when I used $.each in Jquery .
My selection will get some of item with the same value but I want to remove all that value just keep only one.

```
function dropDown(data, selectorId) {

    var selector = '<select  style="width: 400px;" id="results">';
    if (data == '') {
        selector += '<option value="0">No Reference</option>';
    } else {
        selector += '<option value="0">Choose a reference</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            selector += '<option value=' + val.journal_id + '>' + val.reference + '</option>';
        });
    }
    selector += '</select>';
    $(selector).appendTo(selectorId);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array to track the items which are already added.

```
function dropDown(data, selectorId) {
    var journal_idArray = [];
    var selector = '<select  style="width: 400px;" id="results">';
    if (data == '') {
        selector += '<option value="0">No Reference</option>';
    } else {
        selector += '<option value="0">Choose a reference</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            if( journal_idArray.indexOf(val.journal_id) == -1 ){
                selector += '<option value=' + val.journal_id + '>' + val.reference + '</option>';
                journal_idArray.push(val.journal_id);
            }
        });
    }
    selector += '</select>';
    $(selector).appendTo(selectorId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only add if it hasn't been added already.

```
function dropDown(data, selectorId) {

    var selector = '<select  style="width: 400px;" id="results">';
    if (data == '') {
        selector += '<option value="0">No Reference</option>';
    } else {
        selector += '<option value="0">Choose a reference</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            if (selector.indexOf('<option value=' + val.journal_id + '>') == -1){
                selector += '<option value=' + val.journal_id + '>' + val.reference + '</option>';
            }
        });
    }
    selector += '</select>';
    $(selector).appendTo(selectorId);
}
```